# Install GUI for debian

Tags: debian, boot, gui

I did many manipulations when trying to install NVIDIA driver on my debian machine, without success.

I've deleted everything related to debian's GUI (`x11-common`, `xorg`, `gdm3`, `gnome`, `gnome-shell`, `xserver-xorg-core`, `xserver-xorg-video-*`, `nvidia-*`).

Now I've juste access to console mode whene booting, and I'd like to reinstall debian GUI (gnome) but I don't know in which order I've to install all the components above.

Answer (score 0):

(Install and) run `tasksel`, and select what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem on my Debian / Ubuntu / Mint machine getting it to work with an Nvidia GTX-960M. I got it to work by getting rid of everything as you have done, and then by adding xorg-edgers ppa and then installing the nvidia-352 driver.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
```

I also had to upgrade to the 4.5.4 Linux kernel